# How to call default media player from actionbar?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my app would like user to click on a button on actionbar.  This action to invoke default mediaplayer, so that user can select any music as they like.  Need ability to return to the app while the music is played in the background.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works as intended...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//Min SDK 15
startActivity(intent);
```